# How do I update a ContactRole status on the opportunity when the opportunity stage changes

Tags: process-builder

I want to update the ContactRole Status when an Opportunity Stage changes to stage 7 or 8.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] to add details and specifics; see [ask] for more.

Comment: I tried to create a process builder.  Right now I have criteria when a opportunity stages is stage 7 or 8 then I want ContactRole Status to update but can't seem to find the picklist for the ContactRole Status.

Comment: Looks like i may need to create a flow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click +Add Action in the Immediate Actions section of your decision.
2. For Action Type, choose Update Records.
3. Give it a name
4. Click into the Record Type field; in the popup that appears, choose the "Select a record related to the Opportunity" radio button.
5. In the dropdown, choose OpportunityContactRoles.
6. Click Choose to close the popup.
7. In the field assignment section below, you should now see your Status field (I assume this is a custom field?). Choose that, and set the value to the picklist value you want to assign.